# update sequence number in database mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, sequence

I have product list in database and want to mange sequence from the administrator.

If i enter new product in database it will be come 1. (there is already 6 record 1,2,3,4,5,6) new product will be sequence 1. new sequence will be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 and new record will be come on 1.

if during insert new record i want to come on 3rd position than other position number 3 become 4 and position number 4 become 5 and so on.

I am using MySQL and PHP.

I got the answer when admin will add the product we got the new product always as 1st position by using below query:-

// be default position will set as 0

insert into user(name,inum) values('product name','0');

SET @i = 0;

UPDATE user SET inum = @i := @i + 1 ORDER BY inum;

What i need to do if i want to insert new record on position 3 and rest of the record position will increase by 1.

Comment: can you show what you did already?

Answer (score 1):

> Priyank by default if you declare a id column or any name apply **auto increment** than in insert they take auto integer value
>   like 1 than 2 than 3 so no duplicate value is there
>
> and According for your sorting you can use **`order by id desc`**
>
> So You  can retrieve  last data first and so on

After update your question you can use below query

```
UPDATE TABLE table SET ID += 1 WHERE ID >= 9;
INSERT INTO TABLE (ID, ...) VALUES (9, ...);
```

Comment: we can't use the auto increment we add new filed as position in database

I got the answer when admin will add the product we got the new product always as 1st position by using below query:-


// be default position will set as 0

insert into user(name,inum) values('product name','0');

SET @i = 0;

UPDATE user SET inum = @i := @i + 1 ORDER BY inum;

Now what in case if i need to insert new record on 3rd position and rest of the automatically increase

Comment: @PriyankSharma first you need to update than you insert according to my query.....it's work well

Comment: @PriyankSharma if you wan to insert at first than change just where condtion by  UPDATE TABLE table SET ID += 1 WHERE ID >= 1; next you can insert on 1

Comment: thanks for your reply.

i have one filed in database as pos and value is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 and now i want to update position record number 9 to 2 so new position will be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 and record 9 will become record 2 and rest of the records will increment accordingly. please help me out for same

Comment: - first query is increment from 2 to 10 2.chnage value of 10(9 become 10) to 2 coz 2 is now blank -3.11(is 10 after first step it becomes9) to 10